# Excel noob needs help Replacing a mid value with a different value using excel formula

Tags: excel, replace, excel-formula

I'm new to StackOverflow and to Excel formulas!

I'm trying to replace the word "GIL64000" with the word "GIB64000", I need to do this across many cells A2: H6; A9: G13, etc.

The cells themselves contain information as follows: "GIL64000_XX_X" with "*XX*" varying between *WH*, *BL*,*OR*,*PU*, etc and the"_X" ranging from L, M, S, XL, XXL (shirt sizes).

So I have cells with values like: "GIL64000_OR_S" , "GIL64000_BL_XXL" , "GIL64000_MIN_M" , "GIL64000_MIN_L" etc.

I've tried to get the replace function working by doing this: =REPLACE("GIL64000";3;1; "B")
But it only does this within the cell I have the formula in.

I've tried to add A2: H6 to the formula, but it doesn't accept it and returns with #VALUE! error: =REPLACE(A2:H6;3;1;"B")

I tried some other string like "MID" function, but I can't figure out how to use MID with REPLACE: =REPLACE(MID(A2: H6;3;1; "B"))

I tried to follow some guides and I still can't seem to get it working.

In essence, what I Want is the word "GIL64000" with word "GIB64000" across all my cells and to be able to change the formula as I need it in the future for other values not only "GIL64000"

Comment: You are more likely talking about "Macros" , as formulas aren't intended for this behaviour.

Comment: CTRL + H > Highlight range > set Find / Replace criteria - (tick find in values / formulas as required)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REPLACE command only takes in one reference of the cell, and not a range. 
Only Change which you need to make is =REPLACE(A2;3;1;"B"), and then just copy the formula (i.e. Ctrl + C, and Ctrl + V on the other cells where you want to change this).

Also, this cannot be applied on the cell itself but would be applied on an adjacent cell.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Okay so the keyword I was missing here was''range''. I found out that "find and replace tool" actually works for this super easy!

Your method would work, but it wouldn't be the most efficient ( as "Find and Replace" is)

Thanks for the feedback! It really helped :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also the substitute() function which will work, have shown 2 variations - both will drag down, but the second allows customizing the characters to replace. You could put $ on the B3 and C3 for an absolute reference.

See:

[image]

Note: I did not just look for "B" although you could - it depends what other data is there...

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you want a formula, but in this case, don't sneeze at the idea of using a CTRL+H. This looks like the perfect scenario for one.